# Bootstrap Navbar not customizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong in my code. The navbar is supposed to appear at the top of my page in a bluish/indigo color with white font, but instead is coming out as a normal inverse navbar (black and white). Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is my css code for my navbar:

```
.navbar-inverse {
background-color: #1A237E;
background-image: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1A237E;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1A237E;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #303F9F;
    color:#eeeeee;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"  aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="aboutus.html">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                        About
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Desserts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you!

Comment: In which sequence do you load the css files? Your own css needs to be loaded lastly, otherwise the normal bootstrap code will overwrite your code. You can easily check, by right clicking on the element and inspecting in the browser. Those css rules are stroke through which are overridden. But maybe by inspecting you manage to find another mistake, perhaps that your css is not loaded at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I am new to html/css. My CSS is the last line before the </head>. My other css styling is working throughout the rest of the page, just not in my navbar.

Answer (score 1):

I dropped your HTML and CSS into a Bootstrap Template JSFiddle. Everything appears to be fine, and the navigation bar appears to be blue with white text.

Make sure you load your custom stylesheet after the Bootstrap stylesheet or your CSS will get overwritten.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried it on JSFiddle and it worked as well! I am not sure why it isn't working through sublime text? My css file is the last line before the </head>.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for our help! When I opened the inspector I saw my css file wasn't showing completely and stopped before a class I wasn't using. I deleted that section of my css file and the rest of the file appeared in the inspector, including the navbar. Thanks for helping a newbie!